# RHive package connection with hadoop

Tags: java, r, hadoop

I am a beginner and I am trying to connect **R** with **hadoop** using **R** package `RHive`. My codes are as following:

At **hadoop** prompt:

```
u/users/seeker $ export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/bin/hadoop
u/users/seeker $ export HIVE_HOME=/usr/bin/hive
```

At **R** console:

```
library(rJava)
library(RHive)
rhive.init()
rhive.connect()
```

I am getting the error:

`Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Please help me to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated!